# convert string date in python to day month year in python

Tags: python, date

I m new to python. I have a date in the format 1/11/2012 that I need to convert to 11 January 2012. I need to use a procedure given a dictionary: month = {1:January, 2: February,...etc}. If I print (month, date string), then I should get that. Thanks a lot for help.

Comment: Please take a look at the Python standard [datetime](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html) module.

Comment: Retagged with [homework]

Answer (score 12):

Don't reinvent the wheel. You don't need the dictionary.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('1/11/2012', '%m/%d/%Y').strftime('%d %B %Y')
'11 January 2012'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
datestring = '1/11/2012'
months = {'1':January, ...}
month, day, year = datestring.split('/')
print '{} {} {}'.format(day, months[month], year)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> import calendar
>>> mydate = datetime.strptime('1/11/2012','%m/%d/%Y')
>>> calendar.month_name[mydate.month]
'January'
>>> mydate.year
2012
```